# jQuery Change CSS after 1 second

Tags: jquery, css, settimeout

I have what I believe to be the correct code, but it's not working, maybe I just need another pair of eyes to look at it?  I'm trying to change the display style after 1 second.

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function () {
    setTimeout( "$('#imgbl1').css("display", "block");",1000);
  });

</script>
```

Comment: Your problem is the quotes.  Also wrapping in a function is recommended

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You have to write like this.

```
<script>

$(document).ready(function () {
    setTimeout( function(){
        $('#imgbl1').css("display", "block");
    },1000);
});

</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Wrap your code in an anonymous function. Change it to:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  setTimeout( function(){ $('#imgbl1').css("display", "block"); }, 1000 );
});
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/Lffdh/)**

Answer (score 1):

Use an [Anonymous Function](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/JavaScript/Anonymous_Functions):

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function () {
    setTimeout( function ( ) {
         $('#imgbl1').css("display", "block");
       },1000);
  });

</script>
```

`setTimeout` expects a function as its first argument, be this a function handle (i.e. the name of a function) or an anonymous one as above.